# Make Linux automatically determine whether to use SLAAC or DHCPv6

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, slaac

I'm setting up my Debian router. Depending on where I put my router, I need to use either SLAAC or DHCPv6 to get an IPv6 Address (and I **need them both** because I am not sure whether I'll need to use DHCPv6 or SLAAC before I actually get there).

At first I wrote this in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface eth0 inet6 auto
    accept_ra 2
```

but this seems to only work with SLAAC. Then I changed to

```
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
    accept_ra 2
    pre-down dhclient -6 -r eth0
```

but SLAAC is not working.

I wonder if there is a way (or maybe a script or something) to let Linux automatically determine whether to use SLAAC or to use DHCPv6?

I guess I can write a script to run `dhclient -6 eth0` and try to configure SLAAC if no address is acquired via DHCPv6, but I think there must be a more elegant way.

I found `autoconf 1` in `interfaces`' manual page, but it doesn't seem to work (it can be a misconfiguration).

```
autoconf int
    Perform stateless autoconfiguration (0=off, 1=on)
```

To take a step further, is there a way to tell Linux to *prefer DHCPv6 to SLAAC* other than writing a script?